# How can I add a controller to blazor wasm to make stats of my database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor-webassembly

I tried to add a controller to make some stats with the data of the database so I've created a Indicateur.razor page.
The data provide of the CRUD in other page FetchData.razor.
My project is structed as follow :

[image]  [image]

Code Indicateur.razor

```
@page "/developer/indicateur"
@inherits WebApp3.Pages.IndicateurComponent
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor
@using WebApp3.Pages
@using WebApp3.Shared.Models

<RadzenImage Path="images/bateau.png" Style="width:20px" />
<h3>@(result.NombreECR.ToString())</h3>
<hr />

@code {
     
     private Stats result;
    
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
      result = await MonthlyStats();
     }

}
```

Indicateur.razor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Radzen;

namespace WebApp3.Pages
{
    public partial class IndicateurComponent
        {
         [Inject]
         HttpClient Http { get; set; }

         public async Task<Stats> MonthlyStats()
           {
            var response = await Http.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri($"{UriHelper.BaseUri}api/servermethodscontroller/MonthlyStats")));

             return await response.ReadAsync<Stats>();

            // return new Stats {NombreECR=1};
            }
        }

         public class Stats
        {
            public int NombreECR { get; set; }
            public int ratio { get; set; }
         }
}
```

ServerMethodsController.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApp3.Server.Data;

namespace WebApp3.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ServerMethodsController : Controller
    {
         private readonly ApplicationDBContext context;
         
         public ServerMethodsController(ApplicationDBContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        public IActionResult MonthlyStats()
        {                      
           var NombreECR = context.Developers.Count();
         
           return Ok(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(NombreECR, new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
               PropertyNamingPolicy = null
            }));

        }

    }

}
```

The error message that I obtained

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at WebApp3.Client.Pages.Developer.Indicateur.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_4(RenderTreeBuilder __builder3)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at Radzen.Blazor.RadzenCard.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
localhost꞉5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to parse the response.
System.Exception: Unable to parse the response.
   at Radzen.HttpResponseMessageExtensions.<ReadAsync>d__0`1[[WebApp3.Pages.Stats, WebApp3.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at WebApp3.Pages.IndicateurComponent.MonthlyStats() in C:\Users\...\source\repos\WebApp3\Client\Pages\Developer\Indicateur.razor.cs:line 18
   at WebApp3.Client.Pages.Developer.Indicateur.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\...\source\repos\WebApp3\Client\Pages\Developer\Indicateur.razor:line 99
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

I think the structure I've put in place should work but I seem to be missing something.
Do you have any suggestions about the error message and the structure I have defined?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Unable to parse the response.** `Indicateur.razor.cs:line 18 and line 99`.

Comment: Indeed, this is the purpose of my post. Why is it not possible to analyse line 18 and 99?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?  Identify the variable that contains the response in those two lines of code, and evaluate the response to determine why it's not being parsed.

Comment: @Martijn, why do you hidden my last post?

Comment: Include the additional information in your question, not in an answer.

Comment: I've checked the network traffic. All things seems OK with status code 200. The variable NombreEcr = 4, which is the correct equality! Is this from the API call? What about my indicator.razor.cs code? I think there is a problem in

 public async Task<Stats> MonthlyStats()
       {
        var response = await Http.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri($"{UriHelper.BaseUri}api/servermethodscontroller/MonthlyStats")));
         return await response.ReadAsync<Stats>();
        } Do you have any comments? Thanks in advance